# Flink Sliding Time Window - On Element Trigger Emitting Duplicates

Tags: apache-flink

So I'm trying to make a Data stream so that, when an element comes into the stream, it will process each data point from up to 12 hours before the incoming element and then will output the result. So it's a 1 input, 1 output data.

So my initial approach was something like

```
DataStream<ObjectNode> withDistanceTraveled = stream
                .keyBy(obj -> obj.key)
                .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(12), Time.minutes(1)))
                .trigger(new Trigger<ObjectNode, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public TriggerResult onElement(ObjectNode element, long timestamp, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
                        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void clear(TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {

                    }
                })
                .reduce(MyClass:ReduceFunction);
```

If I'm reading the documentation properly then having onElement simply return fire should cause it to fire every time an item is added to the window.

However, it actually seems like the behavior is that it fires reduce function a bunch of times. This data stream actually emitted 1046 results for the initial input of 2.

I tried switching it out for one of the prebuilt triggers but saw similar behavior for the only one that seemed like it'd be relevant (CountTrigger).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, then I don't think you can use a standard windowing approach - or at least not without so many customizations that it would make more sense to just use a KeyedProcessFunction.

Note that since you're using event time, the order in which you receive events might not match their event time ordering. So you'll need to buffer 12 hours + some slop factor worth of events.

And if you really want to generate an event for every input event, then you'll need to handle updating previously generated results that were wrong, because you got an older event that changes the result generated by some previous event which had a more recent event time.